# finding a birthday in neo4j

Tags: database-design, neo4j

So i've been looking into neo4j lately and can't remember the last time i was this excited about something. I just think it's the coolest thing. I still have a lot to learn but...

given something like this:
[image: neo4j graph]

both me and sam have a birthday. his is oct 18th and mine is oct 12th. How though would I find Sam's birthday? would sam have a relation to that date of "born on" or something like that?

I realize I may not be approaching this modeling the right way and that may be my snag. It's just confusing because EVERYTHING is related one way or another it's hard to determine what, if anything, is actually a unique attribute and what is simply a relation.

if I ask for birthdays, I'd want birthday -> oct 18th -> sam and oct 12 -> me.

if I ask for me i'd want me -> birthday -> oct 12

if I ask for oct 12 i'd want oct 12th -> birthday -> me (i think this is right)

so... hoping to gain some insight on modeling things and how i can tie these things together correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you may also be interested in the multilevel index timeline http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html to help you do things like "find all users who have birthdays in October"- if your use cases involve this sort of querying, that is.

Comment: That's definitely interesting and has some of the aspects i've been pondering. I suppose what I don't get is, in my graph above, how do you go from me to birthday and then to oct12th? I'm coming from RDMS so am used to there being "belongs_to" and such. Would I need to structure it more akin to the multilevel index timeline? how would the one date be tied to a user but not the other if you go (user) -> birthdays -> (date)? I fully recognize i may just need to RTFM more...

Comment: Also, maybe mildly unrelated but, in that model they have year, month and day. I thought perhaps it more efficient to store the month/day in  one field as a day_of_year(X/365) since that would (theoretically) tell me already what month, what week, etc. from it's value. But, is this realistically efficient? if I wanted to find birthdays on the first week of every month, would they both be able to answer that question with similar efficiency? or am i just over-engineering...

Comment: First question- how do you go from me to birthday and then to Oct 12? You can use a cypher query similar to the following- start user=node(id_of_your_node) match (user)-[:has_birthdate]-(birthday) return birthday.date_of_birth [Assuming the birthday node has a property with the actual date of birth]. A different user who has a different birthday would have a different birthday node linked to him, so you'd always get his birthday. If both of you share the same birthday, then your node and his both have a relation called has_birthdate to the same birthday node.

Comment: As for the multilevel index, you could store the day of year if you wanted to- but then the burden of calculation falls in your application or your query where you would first calculate what the day of the year is for the first week of a month and query based on that. IMHO the timeline index is nice and flexible if you're really concerned with these kinds of queries (and take a look at the sample queries in the documentation for the timeline to get a better idea).  If your use case is simpler however, a simple birthday node might do

Comment: Ok, so if i understand you... me and sam would have seperate birthday nodes? and if I wanted all birthdays I could query for all birthday nodes vs querying "the" birthday node? And to the multilevel index, I realized that leap years would mean the calculation would be year sensitive which partially defeats the whole purpose I had it for anyway. So, yes i think the timeline index will work for this as well.

Comment: Yes that's right- you and Sam would have separate birthday nodes. You can get all birthdays via the Birthday_Reference relation starting from the root node/timeline. And once on a birthday node, you can find all people who share that birthday. Or you can jump to the birthday node directly if you use the Lucene index that's part of neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

So I guess the question is, what answers are you trying to get here?

You want to get other people who have birthdays? Well this will (theoretically) return all users in a database, not just "Sam", unless you tailor your question specifically to "Sam"

So one way to model this would be the have your reference node, which is common among neo4j models, reference all Birthday nodes, and then traverse like this:

```
(Reference_Node)-[:BIRTHDAY_REFERENCE]->(Birthday)<-[:HAS_BIRTHDATE]-(User) where User.name='Sam'
```

Is this what you are looking for?